# spring session scope form is null when using @Secured

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, roles, spring-annotations

When use @Secured annotation, form(controller's member and session scope) become null.

Form.java

```
@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class Form {
  //members...
}
```

Controller.java

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Form form;

    @ModelAttribute("form")
    private Form initForm(Principal principal) {
        return form;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/someAction", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    @Secured("hasRole('ROLE_CHILD')")
    public String someAction(Principal principal) {
        return "/some"
    }
}
```

some.html(with thymeleaf)

```
<!-- display when form is NOT null -->
<span th:if="${form}">form is NOT null</span>
<!-- display when form is null -->
<span th:unless="${form}">form is null</span>
```

I browse "/someAction", then
"form is null" is displayed.

and change Controller#someAction(Principal) code like below
(delete @Secured annotation)

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/someAction", method = { RequestMethod.POST })
    //@Secured("hasRole('ROLE_CHILD')")
    public String someAction(Principal principal) {
        return "/some"
    }
```

again browse page,
"form is NOT null" is displayed.

if use @PreAuthorize instead of @Secured, it becomes same result.
And Security function supplied by @Secured works fine. I got 403 response.

Why @Secured make form null?

tested on

- spring-security-web:3.2.0.M2
- spring-security-web:3.2.0.RELEASE
- spring-security-web:3.2.4.RELEASE

and

- spring-core:3.2.9

Comment: Try changing the scope of initForm method from private to public.

Comment: Works fine!Thank you very much.I was troubled for two days with headache.